# Continuity of a partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

I have the function

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
       x^2ysin(\frac1x) & \text{if $x$ is not 0} \\
       0            & \text{if $x=0$}\end{cases}$$

And I need to find the derivative and the partial derivatives, and see if they are continuos.

I´ve already proved that the function is continuos for all (x,y). I´ve also found the derivatives:

$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}= \begin{cases} 
                2xysin(\frac1x)-ycos(\frac1x)  & \text{if $x$ is not 0} \\
                0                              & \text{if $x=0$}\end{cases}$$

$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}= \begin{cases} 
                x^2sin(\frac1x)  & \text{if $x$ is not 0} \\
                0                & \text{if $x=0$}\end{cases}$$

And I've also proved the continuity of $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$,
but I have yet to prove that $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}$ is continuos (or not), and find the actual derivate of the function.
 If someone could give me a hand, it would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: How did you compute the partial derivatives at $0$? this is the crucial part of the exercise

Comment: @Avitus Sorry, what do you mean with compute? English is not my first language :) ... If you meant how did I calculated it, I did it by definition and took the limit of $f(h,y)/h$ when $h\to 0$

Comment: Ok, I agree! Hint: what is the limit of the product of a bounded function and one that goes to 0?

Comment: My problem is when x goes to 0 and y doen't. I don't know how to 'formalize' that case

Comment: @Avitus I mean, the term that gives me trouble is $ycos(1/x)$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\sin$ and $\cos$ remain bounded, while the factors they have in front tend to zero as $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$.

But now consider the limit to points $(0,y)$ with $y\neq0$.

Comment: Yes, I've already calculated the limit when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, my problem was exactly when it goes to $(0,y)$. Although I think it doesn´t converge, because $cos(1/x)$ doesn't, I just have to formalize my proof. I'm missing the second part of the excersice though...

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(x,y)$ is indeed continuous at $(0,0)$ because:
$\|\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(x,y)-0\|=\|2xysin(\frac{1}{x})-ycos(\frac{1}{x})\|\leq\|2xysin(\frac{1}{x})\|+\|ycos(\frac{1}{x})\|\leq2\|xy\|+\|y\| \leq
2\|(x,y)\|^2+\|(x,y)\|\to0$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$